# Were the Maquis who returned on Voyager punished for having been Maquis?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In the first episode of *Voyager*, Captain Janeway permits the survivors of a *Maquis* ship to join her crew, even though from a legal perspective they are outlaws at best and terrorists at worst. Later on, the *Maquis* as an organization

> is annihilated by the Dominion.

What is the general fate of the former Maquis members who survived the entire voyage, returning to the Alpha Quadrant on Voyager?

- Are they allowed to continue in service to Starfleet?
- Are they pardoned for any crimes they had committed while in the service of the Maquis as a "thanks" for serving on Voyager but sent on their way (e.g. no more serving on Starfleet vessels, but no particular punishment either)?
- Are they delivered to the Federation criminal justice system to stand trial and/or face punishment for their *Maquis* participation?

If the former Maquis receive individualized evaluations and determinations, for example, a select few who had served with distinction have their ranks confirmed/ratified/made permanent by Starfleet Command, most of the rest are kicked out onto the streets of San Francisco, and a handful who had committed particularly egregious crimes before their Delta Quadrant detour are given prison sentences, that's an answer.

Comment: I feel like there is a question around here somewhere that deals with this topic. Not Voyager and the Maquis specifically, but field promotions in Star Fleet, or something like that.

Comment: @Xantec if you can find it I will accept a close vote. I have been searching and found nothing.

Comment: I guess not. There are some that look like they should, but in skimming the answers they don't appear very helpful for this question.

Comment: I added a spoiler section regarding the fate of the Maquis, as even though the series is quite old by now, that particular piece of information is rather shocking and spoilery.

Comment: @Loki thanks, I think that was a good idea.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ronald D. Moore felt that had the show continued beyond the ship returning to Earth, the money-men would have insisted on the crew remaining integrated and that the only serious way that could happen is if the Maquis crewmembers became fully-fledged Starfleet personnel. He hated the idea and resisted it heavily.

> I said this years ago: it’s giving up on the show. If you bring that
> ship home before the series is over, you have given up. You’ve rolled
> over and said, ‘We can’t make it work. Let’s just go back and do TNG
> all over again.’ It comes back home, goes to Earth, there’s like a
> two-part episode as they go down to Earth and revisit their old lives.
> What’s going to happen at the end of that two-parter? **All the
> characters are going to re-up and say, ‘I love Voyager. It was such a
> family. I learned so much from you. Let’s not break up. Let’s stay
> here.’ All the Maquis people will take regular commissions in
> Starfleet. Chakotay will chose to be second in command to Janeway.
> B’Elanna will embrace those warp engines.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Ron D. Moore - Q&A - LCARS](http://www.lcarscom.net/rdm1000118.htm)</sup></sub>

---

In the EU continuation novel [Homecoming](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Homecoming_(novel)) we learn that with little left to rebel against (and with the dire need for good officers to man ships against the Dominion) the Maquis were issued a general amnesty and pardons for those in jail. The crew of the Voyager were extended the same courtesy on their return.

> “During the last days of the war there was a shortage of trained,
> capable officers. The situation was desperate. **A general pardon
> was therefore offered to any of the Maquis who chose to return to
> Starfleet,** absolving them of any wrongdoing, and after the massacre on
> Tevlik’s moon, it was argued that there was no reason to doubt their
> commitment to the cause. To be honest, I opposed the amnesty. I did
> not think Maquis could be trusted. I have never been so happy to be
> proven wrong. The former Maquis served bravely and loyally. Therefore,
> **I hereby extend the amnesty to all those who Captain Janeway informs
> me have served her so well.”**
>
> Admiral Paris smiled, then spoke again. “Which means I’m spared the unpleasant duty of escorting my new daughter-in-law to prison.”

Comment: I think that the Equinox survivors would still be screwed, though.